# Android 8.0 and plus background service after app killed from recent

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications

I am developing the chat app when user receive new message he should receive a notification. it is working well in android 7.0 and less. But in android 8.0 and above background service stop after app clear from stack. Is there any way to keep service alive to receive notification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run foreground service for Oreo (Android 8.0) and higher. Android will stop your service automatically.
You need to learn about services.
[https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services[1]](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services%5B1%5D)

Comment: Thanks. i want the solution without foreground service

Comment: No you cannot use background services on Android 8.0 and higher. You can check JobScheduler and Work-manager for further detail about background services. May be you will find better solutions.